# Grep or Map a 2D array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dictionary

I'm working on a script where I've imported a CSV which is currently a 2D array as such:

```
    eData[0]=["Del","Trotter","Sales"];
    eData[1]=["Rodney","Trotter","IT"];
```

what I want to be able to do is grep or map to another array using a search string on the second level data, so if I searched for first name beginning "de" `eData[0]` would be assigned to the array or if i searched surname beginning with "tr" both `eData[0]` and `eData[1]` would be made into a new Array

basically the equivalent to:

```
    `SELECT * FROM ad_colleague_info WHERE ad_colleague_info.First LIKE '"+$('#searchbox').val()+"%'";`
```

ok I had to change map to grep, but this appears fully working:

```
    var search = new RegExp( "\\b"+$('#searchbox').val()+"+", "gi");
    FeData = jQuery.grep(eData, function (value) {
        if(typeof(value[0]) != "undefined" && value[0] !== null && value[0].match(search)) return value;
        return null;
    });
```

Comment: Uh, is there still a problem?

Comment: You should really build the regex outside the grep callback

Comment: I made a few more edits for null data and changed it from string start to word boundary, but yep as it is its working perfectly :-)

what is the thinking behind building the regex outside the grep callback?

Comment: performance, of course - it only needs to be built once and not for every match

Comment: yea that makes sense I'll change it